# Display COLUMN number for TRUE in rank preference list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like the option to toggle the display of compiled rank order responses in a grid between "response indicated" and "response indicated by rank number". I'm hoping for a formula solution rather than using Apps Script.

The included screenshot displays the current and desired outcome—with current as the example for "response indicated" (link to sheet below).

[image: screenshot with current & desired results]

The grid pulls from responses on a separate sheet as shown in the included screenshot.
[image: screenshot of input data]

NOTE:

- While the choice order on the input sheet is ordered 1-5, the display grid does not list the options in sort order.
- There is a sort checkbox on map!C2 that informs whether the display grid uses the same order as input or sorts alphabetically.
- The display grid uses separate formulas (B4 & C4—that do not reference one another) to populate.
- The closest I've been able to generate is the first row toggling to the accurate ranking (using various combinations of QUERY, VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, COLUMN)—but unable to generate an array output so that each row can create a specific response.

current C1 formula (uses named ranges):

```html
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
      IF(autoSort,
        TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
          TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
            QUERY(inputTable,"where A is not null order by A",0),
            "select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",","Col"&SEQUENCE(1,5,2))),)),,
          COLUMNS(QUERY(
            QUERY(inputTable,"where A is not null order by A",0),
            "select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",","Col"&SEQUENCE(1,5,2))),)))),
        TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
          TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
            QUERY(inputTable,"where A is not null",0),
            "select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",","Col"&SEQUENCE(1,5,2))),)),,
          COLUMNS(QUERY(
            QUERY(inputTable,"where A is not null",0),
            "select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",","Col"&SEQUENCE(1,5,2))),))))),
      autoOptions),
    CHAR(10003),))
```

link to example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRaRf-0n-VQ2zljqUpk38sMrFlCh19JAcv7IFMeFMw0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: whats the deal with that sorting B2:C2 ?

Comment: it changes the order of how the PERSONS are listed in the display grid (i.e., whether the names are in the order they appear in the input sheet or rearranged to be alphabetical)

Comment: I see, so you want to have both options preserved

Comment: yes, this is a sample sheet—in the "real" sheet, i have options to change how things are sorted as well as limit the number of ranked responses that are used; the last option i'm trying to add is to be able to toggle between check marks and the ranked numbers displayed.

Comment: what will you do next with the column number?

Comment: @player0 don't try to do it all in one with the names, you'll just confuse the OP

Comment: ha. thanks. yes, OP can be easily confused! as for the sorted, if asking for map!C3:K3, it is sorted on a custom display—in the real world example, the options are not listed alphabetically so i made the sample mirror that with the options being out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4:B&C3:K3,SPLIT(FLATTEN(input!A2:A&input!B2:F&"|"&COLUMN(input!B1:F1)-1),"|",0,0),2,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

just a [MattKing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73492628/5632629)'s mod with a checkmark switch:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B&C3:K3, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(input!A2:A&input!B2:F&"|"&COLUMN(input!B1:F1)-1&"|"&CHAR(10003)), "|"), 
 IF(C1=TRUE, 3, 2), )))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: very much approve.  at least you didn't try to stuff the names and ranks in there!  
Continue to disapprove of INDEX() though :P

Comment: tremendous thank you! i realized another limitation/need—is it possible to update the solution for an instance where an "active" column of checkboxes is added to input and the map display grid only uses those rows that are checked? i feel like i can build a solution for the "names" part of the display—but since they are disconnected from the checkmarks/numbers, i continue to need help with a potential solution.

Comment: @eirever can you show the new scenario in your shared sheet?

Comment: thanks for the request—upon trying to do this, i came upon my issue (the mapped responses also needed to be filtered by the new checkbox column (within the QUERY functions). i went ahead and made the changes in the new "map2" sheet. now i need to rework all the nested ifs so the sort, limit, and checkmark toggles all play nicely with one another. if you have recommendations for multiple toggle checks beyond IF-in-IF-in-IF, i welcome your input. thanks again.

Comment: @eirever let map2!B5 be: `=IFERROR(FILTER(personList,activeList=TRUE,personList<>""))`